# How do I make sure that my vote link gets clicked only once by a user for a particular post?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a mysql tables...

'users' with uname(a string) as the primary key.
'posts' with id as the primary key.

'posts' has a columnm- 'votes'

When a user is logged in, he can vote posts. The problem is how do i stop him from voting more than once?

Link:(Note: $q is id of the post)

```
<a href='./vote.php?upid=".$q."'>Upvote</a>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET["upid"])) {
        $plus = $_GET["upid"];
        $query = "UPDATE posts SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE id='$plus'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Error querying database!');
    }
```

Comment: If the user is logged in - you can have a separate table of all users / votes cast for a given posts id) and then if a user has already voted on that post's id - then you can return a message saying thatthey have already voted and can no longer do so again. Then you would amend your query to say - only increment the vote if the userID is not already logged as having already voted for post ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take two steps:

1. Onclick set the link's style to `display:none`. or `hide()` with jQuery.  (UX friendly)  (PHP: on future page loads, do not present the link if a vote is already cast by the user.)
2. In your database, save the action in a new/separate table that only allows INSERT only if unique combination of userid and postid.  Then you can leverage that table to count the total votes for the post id.

p.s. By storing individual votes using unique post id and user id, you can also allow a user to undo their vote if you wish.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was trying to say in my comment regarding the separate table referencing the userID and the postID :)

Comment: @gavgrif I started to write it in a comment, but I actually get irritated by the number of abandoned questions that are effectively answered by a comment, upvoted by the OP, then left to rot.

Comment: I agree - but I have been burned / downvoted by other users saying that my answer should have been a comment  - can't win either way. Anyway - at least we were thinking along the same lines..... great minds...

Answer (score 0):

Are you keeping a record of who was up voted what?  If so, you could do an if statement around the up vote link and only actually display the link if they hadn't voted?

This is the best way, that I can think of to do it as, although you could store cookies / session data, they could obviously easily be bypassed.  **EDIT:**  Just to be clear, I am saying that you should not be using session / cookie data for security reasons, however as mickmackusa mentioned in a comment, using sessions would become awfully bloated as more and more posts got voted on.

Comment: Storing all of the votes in session data, may end up being ridiculously bloated... Consider SO, some users have hundreds of thousands of rep points, they've been around for years and years, and their up/down votes would have quite a volume.  I don't think this is a good suggestion long term.

Comment: I also think its a bad idea to store them as session data, although I approached it from a security point of view, as we all know how easy it is do fake session / cookie data.  I completely agree with your point about getting bloated.  I'll edit my post to make it clearer that I'm suggesting to not use sessions.  Thanks.